# Page does not self refresh after task in Taskqueue is done updating values

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

So I had a problem with a task in a worker's POST command taking way too long and was getting DeadlineExceededErrors. I started using Taskqueues and that part works great now- no more Deadline errors. The problem now is that my main page "refreshes" (self.redirect) before the task queue is done so the new detail is not shown automatically and the user has to press refresh themselves, which is a hassle. Do you have any recommendations as to the easiest way to fix this problem? A high level overview of my app is as follows:

1) Main Handler has Get and Post - Get writes a html page which shows new values after the task in the queue has completed. It also has a form which submits queries to its Post section.

The Post section adds the task onto the taskqueue and then calls self.redirect back to the main html page.

2) The Main Worker has a Post command - this is what is added into the queue. It takes about 1-2 minutes to run and then updates a ndb.Model element with new values.

Back in the Main Handler Get function the ndb.Model element has its .query() function called to return the new values.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A task that takes 1-2 minutes to execute is not suitable for user interaction: users are not used to wait that long. Typically, there are three options to resolve this:

(a) Offer a refresh button.

(b) Start a timer that periodically checks if a task is complete. This timer updates the page when a task is finished and stops. Remember that a user may leave the page which started the task.

(c) Deliver the result of a task in a different way (email or push notification).

Comment: can you give me more information about timers? should I code my own timer or should I use taskqueues again or what is your recommended option? Thanks!

Comment: The timer should run in your client code. Search for JavaScript timer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

If your user is willing to wait that long, you could serve these requests in a custom module, which does not have the time limitation.  See Modules in GAE docs.